# winapi - WM_DRAWITEM - comparing HMENU with HWND

Tags: winapi

I have implemented a custom drawn context menu (`MFT_OWNERDRAW`). When I create a context menu, I get an `HMENU` handle when calling `CreatePopupMenu()`. When I handle the `WM_DRAWITEM` message, I get an `LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT`:

```
LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT drawItem = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
```

The `DRAWITEMSTRUCT` structure documentation describes the `hwndItem` field this way:

> A handle to the control for combo boxes, list boxes, buttons, and static controls. For menus, this member is a handle to the menu that contains the item.

I need to check if the `WM_DRAWITEM` message belongs to my custom context menu. Does it mean that I can compare my context menu handle (`HMENU`) with the `hwndItem` (`HWND`) in this way?

```
//getHighlightMenuId returns HMENU returned by CreatePopupMenu
if((int)highlightMenu->getHighlightMenuId() == (int)drawItem->hwndItem))
{
}
```

Is it correct?

Comment: We don't know what `getHighlightMenuId()` returns.

Comment: Edited - HMENU handle returned by CreatePopupMenu.

Comment: You also need to check that CtlType is ODT_MENU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you would compare the `DRAWITEMSTRUCT::hwndItem` to your `HMENU`, eg:

```
LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT drawItem = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
if (drawItem->CtlType == ODT_MENU)
{
    HMENU hMenu = (HMENU)(drawItem->hwndItem);
    if (highlightMenu->getHighlightMenuId() == hMenu)
    {
        // draw the menu item for drawItem->itemID within hMenu as needed ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I use wParam instead of CtlType to determine a control type ? The documentation says: wParam - Specifies the identifier of the control that sent the WM_DRAWITEM message. If the message was sent by a menu, this parameter is zero.

Comment: @Irbis as the documentation says, `wParam` does not identify a menu, you need the `DRAWITEMSTRUCT` for that. And even though the `wParam` can identify a particular control by its ID, you still need the `DRAWITEMSTRUCT` to identify the control's type, as well as the actual drawing details. The `DRAWITEMSTRUCT` also identifies the same control ID. So, you can ignore `wParam` and just use the `DRAWITEMSTRUCT` for everything.